# Thumbnails should be off by default in lightGallery JS plugin

Tags: jquery, lightgallery, lightgallery-2

Currently, my requirement is, I need to display the `toggleThumb` button on toolbar menu, & at the same time I don't want to display my `thumbnails` by default, only if I clicked on `toggleThumb` icon then only I should be able to see all the **thumbnail images**. (by default the thumbnails should be hidden, till I click on that `toggleThumb` icon from toolbar )

I am trying to achieve this scenario by the below configuration -

**allowMediaOverlap: true,
toggleThumb: true,
thumbnail: false,**

And the output I am getting is, if I set `thumbnail` to `false`, & `toggleThumb` to `true`, then **neither the `toggleThumb` icon is visible, nor the `thumbnails` are visible** in lg-component section.

So, Can anyone please explain me how I can achieve this ?

What I need - The Thumbnails should only display when I clicked on toggleThumb icon from toolbar, and by default thumbnail should be hidden.

What I am getting - If Thumbnails are getting displayed by default.

Comment: Try Fancybox, it has options for this and there are samples in the docs

Comment: ohh Thanks @Andrew for this option, but currently I have already implemented with lightGallery plugin.